# Deleting a queryset using tastypie

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

Tastypie allows deleting objects on resource list.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.9/interacting.html#deleting-a-whole-collection-of-resources

I want to delete a subset of a resource. Assuming I have an api endpoint of `/api/foo/`, I want to do a DELETE to `/api/foo/` with a list of pks and only those objects be deleted, not all objects in the collection.

Is there a way to do this with tastypie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add url by using `prepend_urls` that is responsible to perform deletion.

Like in your class following two methods will be added .

Modify code according to your need . Here I performed authentication first .

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    params = (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash())
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/delete%s$" % params, self.wrap_view('foo_delete'), name="api_foo_delete")
    ]

    ## (?P<resource_name>%s)  will be /api/foo  if your resource name is foo

def foo_delete(self, request, **kwargs):
    """ 
    Get pks to delete from post . 
    pks = request.POST.getlist('pks[]') 
    you can use split if you are sending pks by comma separated .
    pks = (request.POST.get('pks')).split(',')
    """
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
        ### perform delete operation of pk . 
        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'error_message': 'You are not authenticated, %s' % request.user.is_authenticated() })
```

Comment: How can I get the bundle in `foo_delete`? I want to call `self.obj_get_list`, but that require the bundle, which is not available on self.

Comment: @shabda you can create bundle using `from tastypie.bundle import Bundle` and then `bundle = Bundle(request=request, obj=<resource_obj>)` . here `resource_obj` is object that you will get using `<model_class>.objects.get()` .